# mongodb $text with $near

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geospatial

Ok, my goal is to perform a text search on my collection and then filter those results to ensure they fall within my "doughnut" geometry.  Example from mongo site:

[image]

Here's the tough part.  Mongo's documentation confirms that today you cannot combine the wonderfulness of $text and $near:

> You cannot combine the $near operator, which requires a special geospatial index, with a query operator or command that uses a different type of special index. For example you cannot combine $near with the $text query.

Sooo.. Here is what I'm doing today.  Notice my current method does not achieve a "doughnut" geometry (it's is just a circle growing in diameter which return duplicate results as the user "zooms" out on the map).

```
    var vendorResponse = JSON.parse(body);
    var vendorPosts = vendorResponse.postings;

    //Get the location of the user
    var userLat = req.query.lat;
    var userLong = req.query.long;

    //Get the item that furthest away from the user
    var furthestitem = sortedVendorPosts[sortedVendorPosts.length - 1];

    //Calculate the radius of the area
    var radius = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((userLat-furthestitem.location.lat), 2) + Math.pow((userLong-furthestitem.location.long), 2) )

    PostModel.find({
        $text: { $search: heading, $language: 'english' },
        $or: mongoCategories,
        coordinates :
             { $geoWithin :
                 {
                     $centerSphere : [ [ userLong, userLat ] , radius ]
                 }
             }
        } , { score: {
                $meta: "textScore"
            }
        }, function (err, results) {




        });
```

I've attempted to use mongos $geoIntersects methods but I'm banging my head against the wall to formulate this query.  Detailed examples of how to workaround mongos current limitation would be a god-send!  Thanks guys!

Comment: You cannot mix a query with requiring both a "geospatial" and "text" index. The only thing you can do would be a `$regex` operation combined with the geospatial. But their would be no "ranking" happening here so it's a little unclear of how to work around the result.

Comment: You could use [geonear aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) with a regex in the query parameter. This will return results ordered by distance. You could then exclude the closer ones, if you want to exclude those in the inner ring of your donut. As Neil says, you could not rank the text side of things, it would be an all or nothing regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there are a couple solutions in my case scenario:

1. Use Mongo Connect and integrate something like solr or elasticsearch
2. Use Mongo's $in method to perform 'nested queries'.. this requires two queries to db
3. Use Mongo's $regex method (as others described and I've demonstrated below).

   ```
   PostModel.find({
       coordinates: { $near: {
           $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ userLong , userLat ] },
           $maxDistance: maxDistance,
           $minDistance: minDistance
           }
       },
       $or: mongoCategories,
       term: { "$regex": term, "$options": 'i' }
   }, function (err, results) {
       //systematic error. Redirect user so they can report error.
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
           callback(body);
       // if no result found
       } else if (!results) {  
           callback(results);
       } else if (results) {
           callback(results);
       }
   });
   ```

I've reached out to the Mongodb team to see when we will be able to perform searches across multiple indexes.  Hope this is helpful!